# How to send IRC messages every few seconds using twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, irc

The twisted documentation provides an example of [how to create an IRC bot](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/core/howto/clients.html#auto6)

Here is the code I currently have (derived from the above example):

```
from twisted.words.protocols import irc
from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Bot(irc.IRCClient):
    def _get_nickname(self):
        return self.factory.nickname
    nickname = property(_get_nickname)

    def signedOn(self):
        self.join(self.factory.channel)
        print "Signed on as %s." % (self.nickname,)

    def joined(self, channel):
        print "Joined %s." % (channel,)

    def privmsg(self, user, channel, msg):
        print msg

class BotFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = Bot

    def __init__(self, channel, nickname='test-nick-name'):
        self.channel = channel
        self.nickname = nickname

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Lost connection (%s), reconnecting." % (reason,)
        connector.connect()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Could not connect: %s" % (reason,)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    channel = '#test-channel-123'
    reactor.connectTCP('irc.freenode.net', 6667, BotFactory(channel))
    reactor.run()
```

Now I want to add the functionality of sending a message say every 5 seconds to the channel. How do I go about doing that? How do I get the handle to the Bot.msg method from outside?

Answer (score 2):

> sending a message say every 5 seconds to the channel

Have a look at [`LoopingCall`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html), which you can use to call a method every *n* seconds.

```
from twisted.internet import task

task.LoopingCall(yourSendingMethodHere).start(5.0)
```

---

> How do I get the handle to the Bot.msg method from outside?

It's up to you. You create the instance of the `BotFactory`, and every `Bot` has a reference to its factory.